# undefined method `item_path' while working with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to update my create `item` action to work with Ajax but Im getting an error of `undefined method`item_path` which i wasn't getting before when it was responding in regular html format. The item is created and saved but ajax doesn't seem to work properly though.

Here is my _from partial :

```
   <%= form_for [@user, item], remote: true do |f|%>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name , class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a new item " %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Submit Item", class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right' %>
    <% end %>
```

item#create:

```
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.user = current_user

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Item saved successfully.'
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Item not saved. Title is too short or missing. Please try again.'
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('.js-items').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");
   $('.new-item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items/form', locals: {user: @user , item: @item }) %>");
```

User#show view

```
<div class='new_item'>
<%= render :partial => 'items/form', :locals =>{:item => Item.new , :user => @user} %>
</div>
<div class='js-items'>
  <%= render @user.items %>
</div>
```

routes:

```
user_items GET    /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#index
                     POST   /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#create
       new_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
      edit_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
           user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
                     PATCH  /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
```

The error im getting in rails s :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `item_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa4f0d30cd8>:0x007fa4f31b26b0>):
    1: <%= form_for [@user, item], remote: true do |f|%>
    2:   <div class="form-group">
    3:     <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
    4:     <%= f.text_field :name , class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a new item " %>
  app/views/items/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_items__form_html_erb__331698480542899910_70173200751480'
  app/views/items/create.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_items_create_js_erb___3618987352886002527_70173200313760'
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Comment: There is problem in your path setting in your partials.

Comment: @MohammadShahadatHossain I figured it was that since the rails s error clearly says it but idk how I can't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that.

```
<%= form_for [@user, item], user_items, remote: true do |f|%>
```

If it doesn't work then run

```
rake routes
```

in terminal see what's your path.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work  here are my routes for item                   `POST   /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#create
       new_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new`

Comment: i get a completely different error `undefined method `name' for #<User:0x007fa4f14fb990>`